# Deep linking - If opening URL on mobile should redirect to app or if opening on desktop should redirect to specified URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sharing image on Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest. I've landing page URL on click of that shared image. If user opening this URL in mobile, he/she should redirect to our mobile app or if opening URL in desktop should redirect to specific URL. I've searched for it, but not understanding what should I do for it.
Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Recommend using Browser gem for detecting mobile: https://github.com/fnando/browser

All links from social media should be the same and point to same controller action. Then in your controller you can do something like this

```
# require the browser/aliases and extend the Browser::Base object
require "browser/aliases"
Browser::Base.include(Browser::Aliases)

# action
def social_link
  browser = Browser.new(request.user_agent)
  if browser.mobile?
    redirect_to 'MOBILE URL'
  else
    redirect_to 'DESKTOP URL'
  end
end
```